# npx create-react-app is not working whern i create it

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! path C:\Users\admin\Desktop/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token "c" (0x63) in JSON at position 0 while parsing near "cre{\n  "name": "desk..."
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-10-18T15_40_35_751Z-debug-0.log

Comment: share your `package.json` here

Comment: {
  "name": "telegramm-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-telegram-bot-api": "^0.59.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code is unreadable in comments.